# how do I put sbt-assembly in artifactory and have sbt retrieve it

Tags: sbt, artifactory, sbt-assembly

For some reason I am having trouble downloading the sbt-assembly plugin using

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.7")
```

from plugins.sbt.  It says the pom is not found.  I'm using scala 2.12.10 at the moment but this has been an irritation with 2.13.1, too.  As an alternative, I tossed it in an artifactory repository.  When sbt concocts the URL to retrieve the pom, it comes up with

```
http:/.../com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly_2.12_1.0/0.14.7/sbt-assembly-0.14.7.pom
```

as opposed to

```
http:/.../com/eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/0.14.7/sbt-assembly-0.14.7.pom
```

which will actually retrieve it. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking under custom resolvers in the sbt reference manual tells you to match relevant values from the build. Maybe something like:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("red angus", new java.net.URL(
  "http:/..."))(
  Patterns("[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]") ).
  withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
```